# Starting a virtual network interface on boot

Tags: networking

I have an interesting conundrum: I've just finished added a second static IP address to my CentOS 6.x system, but only 1 of the interfaces (the original, the first) is coming up. The new one isn't coming up on boot.

However, the second int DOES come up after running: `ifup eth0:0`

Both interfaces are setup manually, and are configured to come up on boot:

```
[root@myers network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0

    ####
    # eth0 default configuration
    #

    DEVICE="eth0:0"
    BOOTPROTO="none"
    IPV6INIT="no"
    IPV6_AUTOCONF="no"
    ONBOOT="yes"
    TYPE="Ethernet"
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    IPADDR=50.116.63.90
    GATEWAY=50.116.63.1
```

And the second:

```
[root@myers network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0:1
DEVICE="eth0:1"
BOOTPROTO="none"
ONPARENT="yes"
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=23.239.10.173
```

Finally, in the second IP address (the new one), I've tried changing the device name from eth0:1 to eth0:0, but that doesn't work either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi David,
Do you have 2 physical network cards, or just one and you try to create an alias ?
Also, what is dmesg saying after a reboot, about the interface that won't go up.

Comment: This is a virtual machine (VPS), so it only has 1 physical connection. I'll check on dmesg, but don't want to take the server down during biz hours - will try to get to it tonight.

Comment: I ran "dmesg > boot.dmesg" and checked the contents of the file, and don't see anything regarding either of the interfaces. I've grepped and searched for eth0, eth0:0, and ifup, and more... I'm not too familiar with what I'm looking for in the dmesg output, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't eth0:0 have to be eth0 to be considered the parent of eth0:1 (which should be eth0:0... I don't know what happens if you SKIP a virtual device ID) for ONPARENT to work?

Comment: Well, originally I had it set to ONBOOT, and then edited the question today to reflect current settings. I should've made that clear in the updated question. I think you're right though - it should be ONBOOT, and not ONPARENT. However, I found the ONPARENT reference on a Linode Multiple Static IP networking guide...

Comment: That's odd, ONBOOT should pretty much work regardless...

Comment: BTW.... I thought I recognized your avatar! :P

Comment: Your answer helped me find the root issue, in a round-about way. It's fixed now. The solution: Rename the device / interface on the first IP address from "eth0:0" TO "eth0", and then ensure the second device is named "eth0:0".

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one default gateway defined on a system.  Remove the `GATEWAY` line from ifcfg-eth0:0.

Comment: Good call. Unfortunately, making that change from ifcfg-eth0:0 didn't solve the root issue (although ifcfg-eth0 still works, and ifcfg-eth0:0 still works whenever I manually run ifup eth0:0).

Answer (score 1):

I would call the original interface `eth0` and the second interface `eth0:1`

Comment: As I indicated in my original post, I already tried that. Good thought, though.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer here. You were semi-right. The original device's file, and the device name inside the file, had to be set to "eth0", and the 2nd interface had to be set to "eth0:0"